# How can I use ASP.Net UpdatePanels to avoid full postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, triggers, updatepanel

I have a dropdown list called "ddlCountry" that has to update only another dropdown list called "ddlCity". 
How should I use UpdatePanel to load just the second dropdown list instead of do a full postback? Because I think I couldn't get the "SelectedIndexChanged" event without the postback property set as "true" on the first dropdown list

I tryed this

```
<li>
    <label>Grupo Gestor:</label>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCountry" runat="server" Width="356px"
        DataTextField="Country" DataValueField="CodCountry" AutoPostBack="False"
        OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlGrupoGestor_SelectedIndexChanged" />
</li>
<li>
    <label>Gestor:</label>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd_ddlGroup1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCity" runat="server" Width="356px" DataTextField="City" DataValueField="CodCity" />
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlCountry" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</li>
```

Didn't work

Comment: No you can't avoid the page lifecycle, UpdatePanel was designed specifically to cause it on partial postbacks. Also, setting AutoPostback to false on your first list will mean no SelectedIndexChanged event will fire, i.e. no postback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your scenario the best thing will be to used ajax control toolkit's Cascaded DropDownList.

See here how to use it:

[**Using a Cascaded DropDownList with Database**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/32725/Using-CascadingDropDown-with-a-Database)

[**Cascaded DropDownList using Database in asp.net**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/AJAX-Cascading-DropDownList-sample-with-database-using-ASPNet.aspx)

Comment: Thank you man. I had never heard about this cascaded before. Solved my problem with DropDown. But I think still dont know the corret use of UpdatePanel hehehe

Comment: we put controls in update panel which we want to update without refreshing whole page (without full postback)

Comment: The problems is that SelectedIndexChanged is not working without a postback

Comment: I did... but without 'AutoPostBack="true"' when I select another item in my first dropdown, nothing happens. With 'AutoPostBack="true"' the code goes to .cs Page_load, userControl page_load and masterPage page_load.. I want to avoid this

Comment: Cascaded dropdown is not working for you, the articles did'nt helped ouyt